# Can't click on tabs after update

Tags: firefox

I just updated my FF (to version 29.0.1). The interface changed a bit on tabs, which is OK. However, now, when I click on the tabs or scroll when hovering over them, nothing happens.

Right-click shows a context menu. And pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> work too, so I can work with the browser but still...

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start the browser in Safe Mode to see if the problem is the addons, themes, etc...

## Instructions

1. Open Firefox
2. Press the menu button on the top right ([image])
3. Press the question mark ([image: question]
   )
4. Press "Restart With Add-ons Disabled..."
5. Press "Restart"
6. Browse a few pages and see if the problem is gone

Now, if the problem is gone, most likely, one of your add-ons or themes (usually tab-related ones) are incompatible with the version.

Now close Firefox and start it again and disable each addon and start again and locate the faulty add-on or theme.

If none of them worked, maybe it's time to reset Firefox. Doing this, you will keep your:

- Bookmarks
- Browsing history
- Passwords
- Open windows, tabs and tab groups
- Cookies
- Web form auto-fill information
- Personal dictionary

## Instructions for resetting Firefox

1. Write about:support in the URL
2. Press "Reset Firefox"

Comment: +1 for the small images in the reply. Really helping to keep orientation.